# How to fix error: Attempted import error: 'Route' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

-- Update: This started working when I just stopped the development server, quit VSCode and restarted it again. Not sure what caused it.

Busy learning React and ran into this error. I have tried several other SO posts but can't seem to get an answer to my problem.

I'm following the guidance to use only react-router-dom and import BrowserRouter and Route from react-router-dom. But I'm getting an error:

```
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'Route' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my package.json:

```
  "name": "poketimes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

From what I've been reading, other posts still use the react-router separately, but if I'm understanding the documentation correctly, I'm not supposed to do that in this version? Also, I'm following a tutorial that does this exactly and it seems to work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: please use this;

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: There mightbe a dependency problem with react-router 5. https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5/
For now downgrade your react-router to version 4 and check.

Comment: The code seems to work with react-router-dom v5. https://codesandbox.io/s/n5r3vz9980. Can you post a reproducible example

Comment: Look at this issue, probably a mismatch between react-router and react-router-dom https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6639

Comment: @TyroHunter the other doesn't have react-router in dependencies

Comment: Hey everyone. It just started working when I stopped the dev server, closed VSCode, and opened it again and ran it again. Didn't change a thing in the code. I am using yarn start instead of npm start, if that means anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close the server and restart it. It Works Fine.

`npm start` or `yarn start`

Answer (score 6):

problem solved in me

```
npm uninstall react-router
```

and

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

then

```
npm install react-router react-router-dom
```

use version 5.0.0

Answer (score 5):

This issue is happening because of the version of react-router-dom. Try updating the react-router-dom to version 6.

Just run the command:

```
npm install react-router-dom@6.0.0-beta.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. You may have a conflict with NPM and YARN. I deleted my yarn.lock and ran it again with only package.lock; and it worked.

You should only use Yarn or NPM.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this as well...
For me it worked when the version of "react-router" and "react-router-dom" matched.

```html
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import { BrowserRouter, Route ,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'

class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <div className="App">
     <Navbar />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    </Switch>

    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   );
  }
  }

  export default App;
```

try this way

Comment: Please provide a detailed description, why asker needs to import Switch, also please put comment first instead of answer

Comment: refer this link to get idea,why to wrap route with Switch https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 3):

You should add this line to your components.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

My problem was solved by this method.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are using react-router v5 instead of v6-

Follow these steps-

Step 1:

```
npm uninstall react-router
```

---

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

Step 2:

```
npm install react-router@next react-router-dom@next
```

Step 3:  **Restart your server**

And you are all set to go!

Answer (score 2):

**For react-router-dom v6 and greater, use this in your App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import '../styles/global.css'

import Layout from '../containers/Layout'
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import Login from '../containers/Login'
import RecoveryPassword from '../containers/RecoveryPassword'
import NotFound from '../pages/NotFound'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/recovery-password" element={<RecoveryPassword/>}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Changes done from v5 to v6

`Switch` changed to `Routes`

`<Route path = '/' component = {Home}></Route>`

changed to

`<Route path = '/' element= {<Home />}></Route>`

Answer (score 1):

May be this is happening because you haven not installed it. You should run this command:

```
npm i react-router
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Re check the spelling of BrowserRouter or else if the spelling is correct restart the npm using CTRL + C and

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `react-router` and `react-router-dom` like this:

```
npm install react-router@next react-router-dom@next
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem went away after I installe these types:

```
npm i @types/react-router-dom
```

which I found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=react-router-dom).

I had just recently upgraded to `react-router-dom` 6.3.0, and that's when the problem began.

By the way, `react-router` 6.3.0 will install automatically when you install `react-router-dom` 6.3.0, no need to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems your route is depreciated in the coming versions, so use this import:

```
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom/Route';
```

Comment: If anything, you would've imported `Route`, not `{Route}`. Importing `{route}` is essentially importing `react-router-dom/Route/Route`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure what the return type in App class. You are returning BrowserRouter.
So when you do an import you need to make sure you put the correct class name which you are importing.

BrowserRouter is being returned not Router.

So it should be

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

or

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to an outdated version being installed. I was able to run `npm install history react-router-dom@next` and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Switch is kind of deprecated in newer versions, use Routes, it'll act as same.

Answer (score 0):

worked by installing:

```
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

in the project folder

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:  does not exist version <6.
So run:
npm install react-router-dom@6
restart the server and it will

Answer (score 0):

npm i react-scripts@5.0.1 worked for me

if you know the version what are you working the search for that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You must delete folder: "node_modules" and write this:

```
npm i react react-dom react-router-dom
```

It works for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], then edit this answer to explain what you are doing and why.