# Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to use React router and routes but keep getting this error:
[image: Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.]

I have tried the following:

- deleting and re-installing react-router-dom and react-router.
- deleting node_modules folder and running npm install
- making sure react-router and react-router-dom are the same version
- Yes, I restarted my server after every attempt listed above.

here is my index.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Switch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Whoops404 from "./components/Whoops404";

function Pages() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Whoops404 />} />
      </Switch>
    </Routes>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Pages />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "video-react": "^0.14.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: `Routes` isn't exported in `react-router-dom` v5, it is part of v6, replacing the `Switch` component. Just remove the `Routes` component from your `Pages` component and use the `Switch`. Or upgrade to v6 (still in beta I believe so don't use for production code) and remove the `Switch`.

Comment: See my answer here to see if it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331898/how-to-fix-error-attempted-import-error-route-is-not-exported-from-react-ro/73007263#73007263

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know React router has no `Routes` component. I would say you can omit that component as there is no such comp used in their docs.

Similar example from docs: https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch

Comment: Well, now you can know better that there is a `Routes` component: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes and https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/installation/getting-started.md

Comment: React router 5.x might not have it, but react router 6.3.0 does, https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 10):

you have used 'npm i react-router-dom' to install the router. that does not come with Routes.

use 'npm i react-router-dom@next' to install the to be released version that comes with Routes.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** as for your `package.json` seems you're still using `react-router-dom v5`

So you need to use `Switch` not `Routes`, Routes is only for `react-router-dom v6`

**2.** Since you use `react-router-dom v5` then your jsx

```
   <Routes>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Whoops404 />} />
      </Switch>
    </Routes>
```

should be replaced by

```
 <Router>
   <Switch>
        <Route path="/"><App /></Route>
        <Route path="*"><Whoops404/></Route>
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

**3.** from below line remove Routes, i saw it on your imports, since you wont be using it, and its not even exported from `react-router-dom v5` you're using,
again its only on `v6`

```
import { Switch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

**4.** **Just for best practice so your codes becomes clean**,
you can merge these two lines since they're from the same package

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Switch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

so they finally looks likes like

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route,  } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used 'npm i -D react-router-dom@latest' to solve the problem

Comment: npm i -D react-router-dom@latest --force worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check react-router-dom version of your project in package.json and read what documentation tells.

I used react-router-dom v6, so i replace "Switch" by "Routes" and that works for me.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 0):

Router is only available on version 5 of react-router-dom
Either use Switch as alternative or upgrade your react-router-dom package

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Routes and Switch at once. Use only Routes if the version is 6+ and  Switch for v5

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just need to restart the server, then it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to upgrade your React Router DOM version to the latest. And `v6.16` is great. So:

1. Install `react-router-dom` `v6.16`:

```
npm i react-router-dom@6.16
```

2. Import this to `App` component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 0):

To update to v6, uninstall the old version using the following command:

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

then run the following command to install the latest v6:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Then exit the command and run `npm start` again

Check out this great article

https://einternet.net/2024/01/05/how-to-fix-attempted-import-error-routes-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom/

Comment: any affiliation with the linked site / article?