# Routes not exporting from react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Routes component is not importing from react-router-dom. I checked my package.json and I have version 6.2.2, I uninstalled and reinstaled the package, running npm start again after the reinstall. I read the documentation and could not find anything regarding my problem.

Any advice?

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import {Footer, Header, Bio, Works} from "./containers";
import {Navbar} from "./components";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


import './App.css'

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar/>
            <Header/>
            <Bio/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/works" element={Works} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

This is my package.json, as you can see I have version 6.2.2 of react-router-dom:

```
{
  "name": "my_portfolio_website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.7",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is an image of the error I'm getting in webstorm [image]:

Here is an image of my index.js file :

[image]

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not warping the `routes` in the `browserRouter` component

Comment: I just added an image with the error I'm seeing
I wraped the <App /> component in my index.js file

Comment: just so you know you can screenshot your screen in windows by pressing the `print screen` key or `windows + shift + s` with the second way you can also cut the photo

Comment: and try closing completely the code editor and then opening again sometimes it resolve problems like that for me (I am using vs code)

Comment: I just did, I still have the problem :-(

Comment: can you show your `index.js` and I found a similar problem here check the answers maybe they will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331898/how-to-fix-error-attempted-import-error-route-is-not-exported-from-react-ro

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! The problem was WebStorm, so I followed the solution from the post suggested by yuriy636